# Strange result of get_stylesheet_directory()

Tags: functions

the result of

```
<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory(); ?>
```

is

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child
```

a mix of \ and /.
Why that?

Comment: why not? why should it be a problem?

Comment: Forward slash is the path separator on most of the OS, except windows. Windows started to accept both backward and forward slash as path separated since MS-DOS2. The mixed content is probably because you have defined the server path with backslash in the Apache's config file.

Answer (score 0):

Backslash is the default used on Windows OS to define paths.

The foward slash is the default in Apache's config on Xampp (at least it always have benn like that on mine).

Since Windows accept both, you have a mix of them. But that won't do any harm to your WordPress project.

And it will be correct when you migrate to a server since you are using the 'get_stylesheet_directory()'.